# Matlab: Calculate Lagrange interpolaton polynomial

Tags: polynomials, matlab

I'm new to Matlab so I don't even know where to start.

I need to calculate `Lagrange's interpolation polynomial` of some function f in the case when the nodes are the roots of Jacobi orthogonal polynomials. 
Any suggestions where can I start it from?

Comment: For Matlab help see [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/1-d-interpolation.html). You may also have a look at [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:MATLAB): it does not have Lagrange interpolation, but it may provide some help anyway.